# Key Stroke simulation fails with windows desktop is locked

Tags: c#, sendinput

I have an application that uses the [Windows Input Simulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/). I use this to simulate a Ctrl-S keystroke to the parent application.  When the windows desktop is locked an exception is raised

> Exception: The key down simulation for CONTROL was not successful.
>      at WindowsInput.InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode keyCode)
>      at WindowsInput.InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode modifierKeyCode, VirtualKeyCode keyCode)

Here is my code :

```
InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.VK_S);
InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

By design.  The secure desktop is activated when the machine is locked.  Which has counter-measures against programs poking keystrokes into the username/password text boxes.

You can use the SystemEvents.SessionSwitch event to detect the machine getting locked and unlocked.  There is no documented way to detect that the machine is currently locked, you can only see the transitions.

Comment: There is some way to get the input to work however; TeamViewer certainly manages to send input to the logon screen. Presumably this requires sending keys from a service with appropriate rights. (commenting since I offer no details...)

Comment: Thanks.  I figured but was really hoping that there was a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine that it's the Windows API that doesn't react on this kind of stuff when the PC is locked.